# Auto login links via login.jsp with username and password in query string have stopped working

Tags: login

I have a number of hyperlinks for logging into various orgs that look like:

> https://www.salesforce.com/login.jsp?pw={password}&un={username}

When I left work on Friday they were working fine. Today when I tried to use one I was redirected to https://login.salesforce.com rather than being logged in.

Why have these links stopped working?

Comment: Ah, I see now the `www` subdomain as opposed to the `login` subdomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is related to [Knowledge Article 000229717 - www.salesforce.com API Endpoint Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000229717).

Essentially, you need to use https://login.salesforce.com for production and developer edition orgs.

> https://login.salesforce.com/login.jsp?pw={password}&un={username}

---

Since this will likely come up in the near future, I'm also liking to [Knowledge Article - 000271648 Logging of Unencrypted Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271648&language=en_US&type=1)

> Salesforce is moving to eliminate the ability for customer credentials to be entered into URIs. Once the plan to retire this capability is finalized, we will share those details and timing with customers.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is still supported if you drop the `login.jsp` and put the query string after the slash:

> `https://login.salesforce.com/?un=daniel@example.com&pw=hunter12`

**Note to other readers wrapping the login process in this way, be VERY particular to use HTTPS!**

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the login.jsp part could be omitted. The note about https is definitely important.